# Disabled Plugin Now Cannot Access Admin

Tags: plugins, error

As per the title, I have disabled a plugin in admin and now the admin is not accessible.  It returns an Internal Server Error.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to Craft Stack Exchange. Would you mind providing a little more information about the plugin for anyone else who may have the same problem? Was this a plugin from the Plugin Store, or something you built custom?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.  Had to delete the plugin entry from the database plugins table.